# can't switch to different target (runlevel) from rescue shell

Tags: linux, archlinux, systemd

I had a working Arch Linux install, at some point it crashed, I had to reboot it, now it will not boot past:

```
Starting Switch Root...
Welcome to Arch Linux!
```

Nothing is logged.  With `systemd.unit=rescue.target` appended to the kernel command line it boots into a rescue shell.  Then, I try to reach another target:

```
# systemctl isolate multi-user.target
Failed to start multi-user.target:  Connection timed out
```

What does this mean?  "Connection" to what?  Can this help in finding out why the system does not boot normally?

(I originally asked [here, on the Arch Linux Forum](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=194197)  but no one has been able to help much.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had misconfigured `/etc/passwd` and `/etc/group` and `/etc/shaddow` which caused no logging and hid the real problems in failing custom systemd services.  Deleting all the symlinks in `/etc/systemd/system/multi-user.target.wants` allowed it to boot.  Runnning
`systemd-sysusers`
regenerated the necessary permissions.  As explained here:
https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?pid=1513698#p1513698